# C# delete each row in a big CSV file that contains a specific value in a specific column

Tags: c#, csv, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a Unity application and I have a csv file with 6 columns and 5000+ rows. The files might grow significantly. The second column contains either "0" or "1". All rows with a "0" are not needed.

I want to read the CSV file and write every row that has no "0" at the 2nd column into a new csv file, so that I have a new CSV file with only rows that where 1. (The "1" also doesn't need to be in the new CSV file then.)

[image]

I tried something like this, but I removed the parts that didn't work. Maybe someone has a idea. Mainly the index x and i where somehow off. Sometimes it didn't read the first column but I might just have confused myself with the incrementation.

```
    public void UpdateCSV()
    {
        string[] values = File.ReadAllText(datapath).Split(new char[] { ',' });
        StringBuilder ObjStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        
        // x as index for second column
        int x = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
        {

            // if column 2 is not 0 it needs to be printed in the new file
            if (values[x] != "0")
            {
                //using ObjStringBuilder.Append() to pass the values of the row that I want to keep

            }

        }

        ObjStringBuilder.ToString().Remove(ObjStringBuilder.Length - 1);
        File.WriteAllText("Assets/Datasets/UpdatedCSV.csv", ObjStringBuilder.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: Where in the posted code is it “adding” the lines with 1 to the `ObjStringBuilder`? That code appears commented out, however, even uncommented, it is adding nothing.

Comment: Yes, that's what I wrote in the text. I couldn't find a solution that was working so I commented it out here. The best solution was to use ReadAllLines() as Poul Bak suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try: `ReadAllLines` - that will give you an array of lines. Then iterate through all using the `Split` function like you have and check `values[1]`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

public void UpdateCSV()
{
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(datapath);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        List<string> values = new(line.Split(','));
        if (values[1] != "0")
        {
            values.Remove(1);  // or values[1] = string.empty;
            string newLine = string.Join(",", values);
            sb.Append(newLine + Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }
    File.WriteAllText("Assets/Datasets/UpdatedCSV.csv", sb.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Just a heads up, have you checked your posted answer? It has compiler errors.

Comment: Oops, wrote without testing. Now it should work (have also added the necessary 'using')

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I needed.

Comment: The error was: StringBuilder ObjStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

Comment: and values.Remove("1");

Comment: Note though that this loads the entire file into memory. The duplicate link shows two alternatives that are way shorter to write and use streams to not load the entire content into memory first, instead it uses a temporary file on the drive. Still using `File.WriteLines` after filtering a list is way easier then your approach with `StringBuilder` and `WriteAllText` ;)

Comment: Meaning it could e.g. simply be `File.WriteLines(datapath, File.ReadAllLines(datapath).Where(l => !l.Contains(",") || !int.TryParse(l.Split(",")[1].Trim(), out var intValue) || intValue != 0).ToList());` which would also cover more and safer checks I guess ;)

Comment: @derHugo: He also wants to remove the second column.

Comment: Oh fair enough! Still, due to `The files might grow significantly.` you most probably rather want to go for a streamed solution anyway to not have the entire file in memory ;)